# How can I delay the presentation of a DisplayAlert to a user?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have code that presents the user with a dialog box:

```
    public async Task ReviewAppAsync(int count)
    {
        if (count == 0 || await MainPage.DisplayAlert("Review", "abc", "Yes", "No"))
        {
            //  some code here
        }
    }
```

ReviewAppAsync is called from the onStart of my application like this:

```
    await ReviewAppAsync(Settings.Trk2);
```

Is there a way that I could delay the presentation of the DisplayAlert to the user by 60 seconds?

Comment: Use Task.Delay in ReviewAppAsync method

Comment: You could put `await Task.Delay(60 * 1000)` in front of the `if` statement?

Comment: Delay can be added using Task.Delay, but what is the purpose? that could lead to correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use Task.Delay

```
public async Task ReviewAppAsync(int count)
    {
        await Task.Delay(60000);
        if (count == 0 || await MainPage.DisplayAlert("Review", "abc", "Yes", "No"))
        {
                //  some code here
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is indeed the easiest way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you can use the `Task.Delay()` function.

Basically just place it before you call the `ReviewAppAsync()` function. Or from inside that function before it actually does work:

```
await Task.Delay(60000);
await ReviewAppAsync(Settings.Trk2);
```